# Apache Spark generating Closure Table for hierarchical data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to generate the closure table for hierarchical data. I have the following table:

```
node | parent
-----------------
1    | 
2    | 1
3    | 2
-----------------
```

I need to generate the closure table of this as:

```
node | a
-----------
1    | 1
2    | 1
2    | 2
3    | 2
3    | 1
3    | 3
------------
```

I know how to do it in RDBMS using recursive CTE, but looking for solution in Apache Spark

Comment: what is the logic for the expected dataframe?

Comment: Have a look at slide 46 at [https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data]. It explain the closure table logic

Comment: You should explain it in the question instead of telling me to go and understand myself.